# Как вызвать фукнцию Js в html

Tags: javascript, html, функции

у меня такая проблема, у меня есть Js функция, хочу ее вызвать в html, чтобы создать верхнюю панель, почему-то код не работает, вот код js:

```js
let getElement = document.querySelector('header');

function header() {
  let mainHead = document.createElement('div');
  mainHead.className = 'mainHead';
  getElement.appendChild(mainHead);

  function createForm(active, text) {
    let form = document.createElement('form');
    form.setAttribute('active', active);

    mainHead.appendChild(form);

    let addButton = document.createElement('button');
    button.className = 'buttonInMainHead';

    form.appendChild(addButton);

    let add_h2 = document.createElement('h2');
    add_h2.className = 'textInButton';
    let h2text = document.createTextNode(text);
    add_h2.appendChild(h2text);

    button.appendChild(add_h2);
  }

  createForm('/Index.html', 'Главная');
  createForm('/pages/catalog.html', 'Каталог');
  createForm('/pages/info.html', 'Информация');
}

header();
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
```

скрипт собственно подключен конечно же.
Или если я что-то делаю не так, можете подсказать в чем ошибка, и как это реализовывается на самом деле.

Comment: а вы запускаете на сервере или от file:/// ?

Comment: тут наверно нужен как минимум nodejs

Comment: я могу ошибиться, но запись в файл обычный javascript не умеет, по этому нужен какой то серверный язык ... типа php nodejs django или что то другое

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let getElement = document.querySelector('.header'); //тут точку пропустил

function header() {
  debugger;
  let mainHead = document.createElement('div');
  mainHead.className = 'mainHead';
  getElement.appendChild(mainHead);

  function createForm(active, text) {
    let form = document.createElement('form');
    form.setAttribute('active', active);

    mainHead.appendChild(form);

    let addButton = document.createElement('button');
    addButton.className = 'buttonInMainHead'; //тут не button a  addButton

    form.appendChild(addButton);

    let add_h2 = document.createElement('h2');
    add_h2.className = 'textInButton';
    let h2text = document.createTextNode(text);
    add_h2.appendChild(h2text);

    addButton.appendChild(add_h2);//тут не button a  addButton
  }

  createForm('/Index.html', 'Главная');
  createForm('/pages/catalog.html', 'Каталог');
  createForm('/pages/info.html', 'Информация');
}

header();
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
```